# Rails, Slicehost, Capistrano - Deployment port issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm getting a port error when I try to deploy my app via:

```
cap deploy:cold
```

The error:

```
ssh: connect to host domain.com port 22: Connection refused
```

My deploy.rb (replaced sensitive info where appropriate):

```
set :user, 'user'
set :domain, 'domain.com'
set :application, "App Name"

# file paths
set :repository,  "user@domain.com:git/appname.git"
set :port, 9728
set :deploy_to, "/home/ruby/public_html/appname"

# distribute your applications across servers (the instructions below put them)
# all on the same server, definied above as 'domain', adjust as necessary
role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true

# you might need to set this if you aren't seeing password prompts 
# default_run_options[:pty] = true

# As Capistrano executes in a non-interactive mode and therefore doesn't cause 
# any of your shell profile scripts to be run, the following might be needed 
# if (for example) you have locally installed gems or applications. Note: 
# this needs to contain the full values for the variables set, not simply
# the deltas. 

# miscellaneous options
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, :git
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false

# task which causes Passenger to initiate a restart

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end

# optional task to reconfigure databases
after "deploy:update_code", :configure_database
desc "copy database.yml into the current release path"
task :configure_database, :roles => :app do
  do_config = "#{deploy_to}/config/database.yml"
  run "cp #{db_config} #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

I understand the error, but can't see where to make the change.  I figured :set port, would handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting the port in your repository path ? Something like `ssh://user@domain.com:9728/git/appname.git`

I think Capistrano only uses the port you specify in `set :port` to log in your remote servers.

Comment: Changed to:

set :repository,  "ssh://user@domain.com:9728/~/git/appname.git"

But now I have more errors! Hehe.  I'll work on it, and if I get stuck I'll post another question later.  Thanks for your help agregoire!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what works:  you must have

```
set :port, port#
set :repository, "ssh://#{user}@IPAddress:#{port}/~/path/to/git
```

Or also try:
Here's a possible fix.  add ssh_options[:port] = port#  May work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious, but:

- Is the port actually open on the server?
- Have you changed it to something else?
- Is it accessible from the outside?
- Is your firewall blocking it?

Comment: No worries - I appreciate your help.  Yes, port was open - I wanted it to be away from the default 22 per host recommendations.  It's accessible from regular SHH root and sudo user logins.

Answer (score -1):

please try it

```
server "domain:9728", :web, :app, :db
```