# Capifony/Capistrano: Connecting/deploying to one IP via SSH with different ports

Tags: capistrano, capifony

I want to deploy my Symfony2 application to two servers with one IP but different SSH-Ports in one "cap deploy" command:

Connect via SSH to `127.0.0.1:22` and deploy, then
connect via SSH to `127.0.0.1:24` and deploy

How do I accomplish this with Capifony/Capistrano?

I can only find examples where I can deploy to different IPs but not to two different ports to one IP at the same time.

Comment: Did you try:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241337/rails-slicehost-capistrano-deployment-port-issues

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, but that's not what I want. Capifony should connect via SSH two times to the same server, the first time to the server 127.0.0.1 at port 22, the second time at port 24 and do a complete deployment each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @CDub already said:

Use 2 separate tasks and 1 common and just override `:port' value in each of them. Something like that:

```
  task :first do
    set :port,   22
    ...
  end

  task :second do
    set :port,   24
    ...
  end
```